# How can I tell which file is being required here?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading through the codebase of the Homebrew repo, specifically the file here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/8518ffdee19c0c985e8631e836b78624e4926c7f/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb

I see many 'require' statements scattered throughout the file, for instance on line 104 (`require 'tap'`).  The problem is that I see 3 files named `tap.rb` in the codebase:

`Library/Homebrew/tap.rb`
`Library/Homebrew/cmd/tap.rb`
`Library/Homebrew/compat/tap.rb`

Further down in the code I see `Tap.fetch...`, and in `Library/Homebrew/tap.rb` which contains a class named `Tap` with a class method named `fetch`, so I'm confident this is the correct file that's being included.  But conceivably, there could be dozens of files with the same filename, and more than one of those could have identical class methods.  My question is, is there a way to tell which Tap class is being loaded without looking through each of the files?

UPDATE: I think I have the answer to my question (see below).

Comment: The file loaded there is `Library/Homebrew/tap.rb`. `Library/Homebrew/cmd/tap.rb` contains the code that handles the `brew tap` command. It is explicitly loaded in [line 61](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/8518ffdee19c0c985e8631e836b78624e4926c7f/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb#L61) when `tap` is the Homebrew command provided in the command line (`brew tap ...`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this great explanation of how `require` works in Ruby:

https://github.com/ericmathison/articles/blob/master/understaning-require-in-ruby.md

Essentially, it works by looking at the Ruby `$LOAD_PATH` method, similar to how UNIX uses the $PATH variable to look for binary executables when it receives a command in the CLI.  I was able to test this out on my local by making two files in the same directory, like so:

```
# file number 1- foobar.rb 

module Foobar
  module_function

  def bar
    p "foo" 
  end

end

# file number 2- foobaz.rb

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(".")

class Foobaz

  def baz
    require 'foobar'
    p Foobar.bar
  end

end

Foobaz.new.baz
```

Without the line `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(".")` in foobaz.rb, the code wouldn't execute with the simple `require 'foobar'` statement.  I instead had to use `require_relative 'foobar.rb'`.  But adding the current working directory to the $LOAD_PATH environment variable meant that I now had access to all the ruby files in the current dir, so it executed!

NB- it's likely that adding `.` to the `$LOAD_PATH` should go in a config file somewhere, not in the same file as the `require` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `binding.pry` before the `require` and execute `$:` that will be the list of directories in which the require will look up the 'tap.rb' files.

See definition of require:
`If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be searched for in the directories listed in $:.`